# Зачем нужны ссылки на указатели?

Tags: c++, указатели, ссылки, дизайн-языка

Наткнулся на вот такой код, который, как я понимаю, создает указатель и ссылку на этот указатель:

```
int* int_ptr = &x;
int*& strange_ref = int_ptr;
```

Отсюда вопрос, зачем в С++ вообще существует подобный синтаксис, ведь strange_ref, несмотря на то, что является типом int*&, все равно будет иметь такой же функционал, как и int*. Все также можно будет разыменовать эту ссылку и тд. Почему этот синтаксис вообще существует и где он применяется?

Comment: `void change_ptr(int *&p) { p = ...; }`

Comment: Неявно такой синтаксис возникает в шаблонах.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy А можно немного подробнее? Не понятно из этого короткого примера

Comment: В ответе ниже сразу обе ситуации: меняем указатели местами в шаблонной функции.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ну вот конкретный практический пример: типичная функция навроде swap без проблем работает с указателями, принимая их по ссылке, как и другие объекты:

```
template<typename T>
void swap(T & left, T & right)
{
    T tmp{left};
    left = right;
    right = tmp;
}
```

Или несколько операций с предварительно выбранным одним указателем:

```
int * p1{};
int * p2{};
int * & pcur{cond ? p1 : p2};
... // много операций, изменяющих pcur;
```

Собственно указатели являются такими же объектами, как и все остальные, и для них можно использовать все те же сценарии работы со ссылками.

Comment: Но какой смысл принимать указатель по ссылке, в чем профит? Или это сделано лишь для того, чтобы можно было принимать различные типы, помимо указателей, например в шаблонах?

Comment: @ComeInRage Если принимать указатель не по ссылке, а по значению, то тогда бы исходный указатель не изменился. А если бы по указателю, то получился бы нужен еще один слой из разыменований.

Answer (score 3):

> несмотря на то, что является типом int*&, все равно будет иметь такой же функционал, как и int*

А вот и нет.

```
int x = 1, y = 2;
int *a = &x;
int *b = a;
int *&c = a;
a = &y;
std::cout << *b << '\n'; // 1
std::cout << *c << '\n'; // 2
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, но у вас указателю присваивается int. Из-за этого не совсем понятно, что вы хотели сказать)

Comment: Однако я понял в чем разница. Но все равно не понятно, зачем этот синтаксис вообще нужен. Но спасибо за ответ, хоть прояснилась ситуация

Comment: @ComeInRage ссылка это почти тоже самое что и указатель, только ссылка не может быть невалидной в отличии от указателя.

Comment: @ComeInRage, ну пропустил он один амперсанд.

Answer (score 0):

Ссылка на указатель оправдана, например, если она параметр функции или операнд перегруженного оператора. Да, эта ссылка имеет синтаксис не целевой величины, а указателя. Но если функция должна не взять готовый указатель у вызывающего кода, а вернуть его в вызывающий код, но сделать это через параметр, то по указателю это сделать нельзя, так как он указывает на целевую величину, а не на указатель.

```
    size_t f(int *p)
    {
     size_t s;
     s=(512+((rand())% 1024));
     p=new int [s];
     return s;
    }
    int main ()
    {
     int *x;
     int *y;
     f(x);
     return 0;
    }
```

Здесь p – указатель не на x, а на память, выделенную оператором new. А где лежит x? Функции надо знать именно это, только тогда она сможет положить в этот x указатель на память, выделенную оператором new. Куда класть адрес выделенной памяти? В x? Или в y?

```
    size_t f(int *&p)
    {
     size_t s;
     s=(512+((rand())% 1024));
     p=new int [s];
     return s;
    }
    int main ()
    {
     int *x;
     int *y;
     f(x);
     delete [] x;
     return 0;
    }
```

А вот здесь всё в порядке, p – ссылка на x, теперь можно в этот x положить значение, возвращённое оператором new. А вот x уже будет указателем на память, выделенную по new. Или Вы не это имели ввиду?

Answer (score 0):

Могу дополнить уже данные ответы своей интерпретацией. Возможно кому-то так будет проще разобраться.

Смысл *ссылки на указатель* в том чтобы работать с *исходным указателем*. дело в том, что если передать просто *указатель* - это работает как передача по значению, то есть изменения переданного *указателя* внутри метода или функции не приводят к изменению значения исходного (переданного) *указателя*. изменится только его локальная копия. если вам нужно модифицировать не **объект, расположенный в памяти** на которую указывает аргумент, а сам **адрес** на который указывает аргумент - кажется нет другого выхода кроме как передавать указатель по ссылке (*ссылку на указатель*). да, синтаксис при этом останется как при использовании обычного *указателя*.